# Supplying a manual foreign key as `sa_column` in sqlmodel

Tags: sqlmodel

I want to have a foreign key on a child model that is set to null when the parent model is deleted (this is default behaviour in sqlmodel when the parent model has a backreference to the child model but I don't have that).
In order to that one can use `ForeignKey(..., ondelete='SET NULL')` in sqlalchemy. To use this behaviour in sqlmodel I'm doing:

```
class Channel(SQLModel, ...):
  ...
  dataset_id: int | None = Field(
        sa_column=Column(Integer, ForeignKey('dataset.id', ondelete='SET NULL')),
    )
```

But I'm getting the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Channel.dataset - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

If I just use `Field(foreign_key='dataset.id')` for the `dataset_id` field then it works. I looked through the sqlmodel code -- If it sees the [sa_column](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/blob/43a689d369f52b72aac60efd71111aba7d84714d/sqlmodel/main.py#L420) arg in the field defnition. Otherwise it builds the `Column` instance from the args provided and supplies the [foreign_key](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/blob/43a689d369f52b72aac60efd71111aba7d84714d/sqlmodel/main.py#L437) arg as is to instantiate a `ForeignKey` instance. I removed `ondelete` in the call above to check if that was causing the problem since it was the only difference but that didn't work either. What could be the problem here?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76525318/edit) your question to provide an actual [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy-paste verbatim, the versions of SQLModel and Python you are using, and the full error traceback.